# dos2unix support for file with unicode characters

Tags: dos2unix

i use dos2unix to remove control-m characters, i works fine for normal text file. But for text files with unicode characters it replaces all unicode characters with junk character. Please let me know how to use dos2unix for files with unicode characters

Answer (score 0):

It depends which implementation and version of dos2unix you use. This implementation (http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html) supports Unicode since version 6.0.

Comment: If you're using a package from a distribution, it might be written in the package documentation. Otherwise, you may install it yourself. At last you can use some other program, that doesn't leave any doubt. Either a unicode compliant scriptable editor (e.g. vim), scripting language, or a dedicated third party dos2unix replacement with a different and unique name, such as flip or endlines.